# Fresh cranberries OR frozen cranberries

Tags: baking, substitutions, cranberries

I have a recipe that calls for 1 1/2 cup of fresh cranberries mixed with 1 cup of sugar (let stand). Then you add egg whites, orange juice and vanilla. Finally, you fold with whipped cream.

Since cranberries are seasonal (and out of season right now) can I use frozen berries in this recipe and have the same results?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, cranberries freeze extremely well.

Since you will be macerating them with sugar, and since the texture of fresh cranberries is not that pleasant anyway, any slight softening from the freezing should not be a detriment--it might even be an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Freezing the fruit, almost cooks the fruit up to 50% depending to the fruit. So when you mix that frozen fruit with sugar or macerate it, your fruit tends to become softer than its  fresh kind.  However,  cranberries freeze really well, and go through minimal change.To control your mixture concentration, use less orange Juice and add more later, if needed. Also consider cutting from the egg whites just by 10% and that should help too.
Good luck

Comment: Freezing in no manner cooks fruit.  It may damage cell walls and thus make it softer or more weepy but it does not cook it and coagulate or denature proteins.